# Ionic Capacitor: How to restrict Gallery from Camera options?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

for an app that I'm building, I'm using Capacitor's Camera plugin. When I click the button that launches the camera, it's asking me to first choose between Gallery and Camera.

I'd like to turn the "Pick from Gallery" feature off.
Is there any solution for this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the Camera plugin prompts, but you can select Camera or Gallery by passing the source attribute

```
// The source to get the photo from. By default this prompts the user to select either the photo album or take a photo. Default: CameraSource.Prompt
source ?: CameraSource;
```

Full example:

```
const image = await Camera.getPhoto({
    quality: 90,
    resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
    source: CameraSource.Camera
});
```

Comment: This only changes the default option but doesnt disable it. At the time of this comment, there is no official option to disable or restrict a user from choose photos from the gallery on Capacitor.

Comment: What are you talking about? If you choose camera it uses the camera and doesn’t prompt you anymore.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Your solution sets the `default` source to the camera and disables the prompt, which OP wanted. However, the user can still choose from the gallery. @Francisco is referring to something else: Disabling the ability to select photos from the gallery.

Comment: That’s only true for web platform if using pwa elements, it’s a problem on pwa elements that includes a “gallery” button. If not using pwa elements then the gallery shouldn’t be available.